# RPN calculator with additional functions

Tags: java

I want to make the code use the stack class (stack of integers), together with a driver program which can handle the operations: 'm' unary minus -- negate the top item, 'r' exchange the top two items, 'd' duplicate top item on the stack, 'p' print (to the screen) the top item, n print and remove the top item, f print all the contents of the stack (leaving it intact), c clear the stack, 'q' quit, 'h' (or ?) print a help message.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CalculatorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String expression;
        int result;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do
        {  
           calculator evaluator = new calculator();
           System.out.println("Enter a valid post-fix expression one token " +
                           "at a time with a space between each token (e.g. 5 4 + 3 2 1 - + *)");
          System.out.println("Each token must be an integer or an operator (+,-,*,/,%)for help(h/?)");
          expression = in.nextLine();

          result = evaluator.evaluate(expression);
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println(result);

    }
    while (result = 'q');
    System.exit(0);

}
```

}

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class calculator 
{
      private Stack<Integer> stack;

      public calculator()
{
    stack = new Stack<Integer>();

}

public int evaluate(String expr)
{
    int op1, op2, result = 0, help;
    String key;
    Scanner parser = new Scanner(expr);

    while (parser.hasNext())
    {
        key = parser.next();

        if (isOperator(key))
        {
            op2 = (stack.pop()).intValue();
            op1 = (stack.pop()).intValue();
            result = evaluateSingleOperator(key.charAt(0), op1, op2);
            stack.push (new Integer(result));
        }
        else
            stack.push(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(key)));
    }
    return result;
}
private boolean isOperator(String key)
{
    return ( key.equals("+") || key.equals("-") ||
             key.equals("*") || key.equals("/") ||
             key.equals("h") || key.equals("?") ||
             key.equals("p") || key.equals("n") ||
             key.equals("d") || key.equals("r") ||
             key.equals("c") || key.equals("f") ||
             key.equals("%") || key.equals("m") ||
             key.equals("q") );
}
private int evaluateSingleOperator(char operation, int op1, int op2)
{
    int result = 0;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
            result = op1 + op2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = op1 - op2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = op1 * op2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = op1 / op2;
            break;
        case 'p':
            result = op2;
            break;

        case '%':
            result = op1 % op2;
            break;
        case 'm':
            result = --op1;
            break;
        case'q':
            result = (0);
            break;
        case'h'|'?':
        int help = 0;
        result = help;
            break;
        case 'r':
            result = op1 ;//help
            break;
        case 'd':
            result = op1;//help
            break;
        case 'n':
            result = op1;//help
            break;
        case 'f':
            result = op1;//help
            break;
        case 'c':
            result = op1;//help
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

private void help(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("+ add the top two items" + 
            "* multiply the top two items" + 
            "- subtract the top item from the next item" + 
            "/ integer divide the second item by the top item" + 
            "% find the integer remainder when dividing the second item by the top item" + 
            "m unary minus -- negate the top item" + 
            "r exchange the top two items" + 
            "d duplicate top item on stack" + 
            "p print (to the screen) the top item" + 
            "n print and remove the top item" + 
            "f print all the contents of the stack (leaving it intact)" + 
            "c clear the stack" + 
            "q quit" + 
            "h (or ?) print a help message");
}
```

}

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: `while (result = 'q');` is an unfortunate typo, and should be causing a compiler error. I stopped reading there.

Comment: Another suggestion, don't automatically pop _two_ operands off the stack when you see any operator;  that's fine if you're only doing binary operations like `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, but it won't work for unary operators like `m` and `d`.

Comment: I am trying to make the code stop working after the user inputs a for quitting but after I run it does not let me place any more letters or numbers for more commonds

Comment: how can I make so that it also reads unary operators.